# Multithreading in windows forms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a windows application, apart from main thread there is another thread which does a long run operation for every minute and updates the UI using Invoke method.

How can we terminate the another thread gracefully when it is in sleeping state?

Is it a right choice of using sleep here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as graceful thread termination. Instead, your thread should be instructed to stop doing it's job once it's no longer needed. You could do this by creating class to hold worker thread parameters inside which you store information whether work should be stopped, and pass an object of that class to the thread.

```
public class WorkerParams
{
    public bool Stop = false;
}

private void TestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _thread = new Thread(lonRunThread);
    _thread.Start(new WorkerParams());
}

public void lonRunThread(object argument)
{
    WorkerParams param = argument as WorkerParams;
    DateTime lastExec = DateTime.MinValue;
    while(!param.Stop)
    {
        if (new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - lastExec.Ticks).TotalSeconds >= 60)
        {
            Operation1();
            Invoke(new UpdateDelegate(updateState));
            Operation2();
            Invoke(new UpdateDelegate(updateState));
            lastExec = DateTime.Now;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the above approach makes the end user to wait for <=1 minute to stop the process.

Comment: Then you will need more complicated handling. Do sleep with 1000ms, and count whether enough time has passed since last execution.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of making the thread once and then terminating, perhaps use a form timer to trigger a background worker thread every 60000 milliseconds?  You then don't need to sleep the background thread at all.

This means you only need to stop the timer to stop more background tasks from being spawned, but obviously this doesn't stop any currently active background thread.

Threads should very rarely be aborted, as there isn't any great mechanism available for doing it with any consistency.  There are various guards such as critical code markers.  However, I think it's best to have the long running code poll for cancellation, then you can code your own logic for abandoning ship and returning early.  **Note**, this is not the same as aborting a thread forcefully.

I don't think sleep is the right choice in almost any circumstances.

For example:

```
private bool _askedToCancel;

public void lonRunThread()
{
    if (!_askedToCancel)
    {
        Operation1();
        Invoke(new UpdateDelegate(updateState));
    }

    if (!_askedToCancel)
    {    
        Operation2();
        Invoke(new UpdateDelegate(updateState));
    }
}
```

Seems a little messy, however you retain very good control over what logic is performed if you refuse to abort threads forcefully and instead use the cancellation approach.

Because this isn't critical code, and because actions on booleans are atomic, you should be safe having both threads talk to the bool without any locking.  And even if it's not *truly* safe, the only result is some more work is done.

Comment: OPeration1() and Operation2() can also be executed by other backgroundWorker threads.

Comment: @user186246 Indeed but the idea is the same.  Expose the ability to push a cancellation request (usually a simple flag), then code deeper down doing the operations can periodically check this flag.  Your own code can then decide how to clean up quickly knowing that the thread needs cancelling.  This means you don't have to do anything to the thread itself.  If you provide a quick code path get out, the thread will be finished with and close itself nicely.

Comment: You mean shall i go with backgroundWorker and Timer . forevery 1 minute it should start worker asynchronously . Even then how can we exit the current thread gracefully when the form is closed ?

Comment: @user186246 I'd advise using the cancellation idea instead of killing the thread.

Comment: sorry i didnt get your approach

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the thread to be a background thread, that way when the application exits the thread will automagically be stopped.

When do you want the thread to be stopped?

If you want it stopped in mid-operation a boolean flag would be appropriate.

So instead of

```
while(true)
```

You would do something like

```
while(exit == false)
```

Comment: Actually OPeration1() and OPeration2() are having some unmanaged code.If the thread is terminated abruptly when operation1() or operation2() is being processed then it would lead to memory leaks.

Comment: On a side note, do you have to use pointers in your unmanaged code?

Comment: I understand that.  My question was can you get away without using pointers i.e. you mite have C c = new C();  however you could write it so the object is automagically destroyed when the function goes out of scope i.e C c; c.long_operation();

Comment: No . currently it is not possible to destroy the object automatically when it goes out of scope as the memory is allocated and deallocated in the unmanaged code.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the while(true) in longRunThread method and make it

```
while (_RunLongThread)
```

then in the TestForm I would declare the private Boolean _RunLongThread = true and set it to false from whichever method needs to stop the long running thread.

Thats a "graceful" way of stopping it i.e. waiting to complete its current task and then terminates